# Not able to scroll down page using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2, javascript

I want to scroll down a page that is coming inside a form, not on the main page.

I tried this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

[image]

The above code is not able to pick the scroll bar as it is not in the main page

Comment: I referred that but my question is different. In that question he is getting the scroll bar is in main page
My scenario is
Open website -> select a menu -> a form inside the main page will open and the scroll bar is inside that.
screenshot of html -> http://prntscr.com/4ksrn0

Comment: Did you try what I mentioned in the above my comment (if the scroll is in different page then move to that page or switch to particular window).

Comment: yes, I tried that but the thing is findelement commands are working on that window without switching but the scroll is not working.
Let me give you an example
Go to www.flipkart.com then click on Trimmer link
screenshot -> http://prntscr.com/4ku57a
Then it will take you to the next page
Now in the left side you can see the brand section and there is a scroll bar present there
Screenshot -> http://prntscr.com/4ku5ke
I want to operate that scroll bar
Could you please give me code for this scenario

Comment: Are you trying to find a particular element by scrolling, or you just want to arbitrarily scroll down?  If you want to scroll in order to view a specific element, you can use the scrollIntoView or scrollTop javascript methods.

Answer (score 10):

Please use below code.

```
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Trimmer")).click();
WebElement scroll = driver.findElement(By.id("brand"));
scroll.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I tried the code but it gave me this error
`Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=37.0.2062.103)
`
Please re-check once

Comment: @Som Ghosh Try with FF and let me know.

Comment: @Som Ghosh Please do not stick with one browser, verify with other browser also. If it is not work with one browser then it's different issue.

Comment: @Sachin  The problem is my product will only run in chrome due to some coding issues so as of now have to verify in chrome only

Comment: You can use the Actions class to do so without any issue in Chrome. Simply using key strokes doesn't work out. I too got the same exception of Chrome not being able to focus on the element.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the ActionChains (Actions in Java) class to do so. I tested the above code in both FF and Chrome and I am able to scroll down using the `Keys.PAGE_DOWN` keystroke.

```
    driver.get('http://flipkart.com/')

    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Bath Towels').click()



    WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"offertags")))


    act= ActionChains(driver)
    act.move_to_element(driver.find_element_by_id('offertags')).click()
    act.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()
```

I first used the `click( )` method to click on the webelement and then sent the key stroke.

Comment: This `I first used the click( ) method to click on the webelement and then sent the key stroke.` is really the key here

Answer (score 1):

I try the scroll down with loop, it's great with Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-

scroll_time = 13

...

scroll = driver.find_element_by_id("element_name")
for num in range(0, scroll_time):
    scroll.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)

...
```

Comment: I believe he mentioned something with the find_element not working. I'm just not enough of a Selenium guy to follow the whole conversation. :-p

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might help:

```
public static Object scrollElementIntoView(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}
```

Where `element` is the object to which we want to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, it worked for me -

```
((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: Can you post your code here which is used for scrolling?
Make sure you have replaced the web driver obeject ('d') with your object.