# Webdriver : How to perform scroll down an element (example div) using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

The Scroll element in the page is actually a div with scroll bound to it. Here is the HTML snippet.

```
<div class="slimScrollBar" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0%  rgb(137, 137, 137); width: 12px; position: absolute; border-radius: 0px; z-index: 99; right: 1px; top: -13px; opacity: 0.6; height: 224.835px; display: block;"/>
```

I have tried with the following code, but it didn't  work out

```
WebElement scrollArea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.slimScrollBar"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];",scrollArea, 250); 
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Help is appreciated!

Comment: This is same as/duplicate of http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/9655/not-able-to-scroll-down-page-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: It doesn't worked for me. The problem is, the scroll bar is only visible when the mouse over is performed in the particular div. So its throwing "unknown error: cannot focus element"

Comment: Can you give me an example. I think you can overcome this by using a wait, so that until element is focussed, the webdriver will wait.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to scroll down to bottom of div with data loading dynamically](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-div-with-data-loading-dynamically)

Answer (score 4):

For   **Scroll down**:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

or, you can do as follows:

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
```

For **Scroll up**:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)", "");
```

OR,

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Comment: How would you scroll to the exact position of the webelement

Answer (score 3):

You could try this.

```
WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.xpath("enter xpath which element is in end of the div"));

Coordinates cor=((Locatable)e).getCoordinates();

cor.inViewPort();

Thread.sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more background to your answer.  Why is this solution useful in this situation?  What are the pros/cons of this approach?  The more detailed context you can give the more the answer will help others.

Comment: ??? what's this now?

Comment: This worked for me. I searched a lot but just this one works. I want to say you are beautiful and amazing. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some HTML page have internal (custom) scroll bar. We have to handle with little bit different way.

Javascript is not working here.

**Solution :**

```
WebElement scrollArea = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.slimScrollBar"));
```

Create method **scroll_Page** as given below.

Call this method as `scroll_Page(scrollArea ,100);`

Where **scrollArea** is your dragged(scroll) element and **100** is scroll points.

```
public static boolean scroll_Page(WebElement webelement, int scrollPoints)
{
    try
    {               
        Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);
        // drag downwards
        int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 10;
        for (int i = 10; i < scrollPoints; i = i + numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown)
        {
            dragger.moveToElement(webelement).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release(webelement).build().perform();
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Python:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("viewport").scrollTop += 100')
```

> In Java:

```
driver.executeScript('document.getElementById("viewport").scrollTop += 100');
```

Comment: Or simply `driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(X, Y)')`

Comment: Yes, this works fine until you try to scroll in a certain item that has its own scroll bar.