# Unable to scroll down to bottom of div with data loading dynamically

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, selenium2

```
<div id="findingTblBody" class="tablebody" infinite-scroll-distance="2" 
infinite-scroll="loadMoreData()" style="width: 819px;">
```

I want to scroll to the bottom of div mentioned above.
    I am trying with this -

```
do {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='findingTblBody']")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
    Thread.sleep(6000);
    scroll_count++;
} while(scroll_count<20);
```

I am receiving error as - `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element`

How to scroll my web page up to that element & click?

Comment: Check this : http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-finding-webelements-using-map/

Answer (score 11):

> *Check below are the various methods to scroll your web page up & down:*

**Scroll Down:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250)"); //y value '250' can be altered
```

**Scroll up:**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)"); //x value '250' can be altered
```

**Scroll bottom of the Page:**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
(or)
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
```

**Full scroll to bottom in slow motion:**

```
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if(second >=60){
            break;
        }
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,400)", ""); //y value '400' can be altered
            Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

(or)

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
for (int second = 0;; second++) {
        if(second >=60){
            break;
        }
            jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,800)", ""); //y value '800' can be altered
            Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

**Scroll automatically to your WebElement:**

```
Point hoverItem =driver.findElement(By.xpath("Value")).getLocation();
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.title;");    
Thread.sleep(6000);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+(hoverItem.getY())+");"); 
// Adjust your page view by making changes right over here (hoverItem.getY()-400)
```

(or)

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("Value')]")));
(or)
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Value"));
Coordinates coordinate = ((Locatable)element).getCoordinates(); 
coordinate.onPage(); 
coordinate.inViewPort();
```

Comment: Hi, Can any of the above cope with lazy loading pages? I know about Waits.