# WebdriverIO browser.scroll() always scrolls to the top?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, nodejs

I am using [WebdriverIO](http://webdriver.io/api.html) and I want to scroll to an element.

But no matter if I'm using `element.scroll()` or `browser.scroll(0,yLocation)` it will always scroll to the top of the page.

Is it possible there is a problem if the page itself has some auto-scrolling?

The answer to [this question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-div-with-data-loading-dynamically/18802#18802) helps for one of my elements which is at the bottom of the page, but I haven't been able to find a way to scroll to the element in the middle of the page.

Comment: Use answer from this question: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-div-with-data-loading-dynamically/18802#18802

Comment: @BharatMane why do you think this is a dup and that question has an answer? There are just the different ways to scroll to an element but that does not answer the question stated here. I would say this cannot be considered as a dup unless the question author add more details to the question.

Comment: @AlexeyR. i dont know what more of details i could give you.

Comment: @BharatMane that answer helps for 1 of my elements which is located at the bottom of the page, however the approach of scrolling to an element which is in the middle of the page does not work.

Comment: I have edited the question to add information from the comments

Comment: which webdriver io version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

We now have an API for this. See [scroll into view](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/scrollIntoView.html)