# Scroll to element stopped working

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I'm using this method, for scroll down till the element is visible:

```
var element = driver.FindElement(By.id("element-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

It stopped working,
with last version of Chrome 65.0.3325.146, Chrome driver 2.36 and Selenium 3.10

Do you have any information, what happened with this method?

Do you have any suggestions, how to scroll till element is visible?

It is not a duplicate.
[Unable to scroll down to bottom of div with data loading dynamically](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-div-with-data-loading-dynamically)
not resolved my problem.

Comment: What does exactly happen? Does it return any error or exception?

Comment: I can not scroll to an element at the bottom of the page. No error, no exeption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to scroll down to bottom of div with data loading dynamically](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18796/unable-to-scroll-down-to-bottom-of-div-with-data-loading-dynamically)

Comment: Not a duplicate. Looks like Se3 broke the `actions.MoveToElement` behavior, as @SahilMutreja noted in his answer.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. Unable to scroll down to bottom of div with data loading dynamically not resolved my problem.

Comment: Does it work if you downgrade to Chrome 64?

Comment: Yes, it works with Chrome 64.

Comment: The Selenium driver 3.11 update has resolved this issue.
Thank you all for effort to help.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium 3 has no support yet for Actions class driver.
[Please Check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41114265/3406534)

You can try out my following code snippet. 
It does exactly what you need.

```
 //@param element is the WebElement that you want to scroll to and then click
    public void scrollIntoViewClick(WebElement element) { 
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
    }
```

Above function uses selenium to execute vanilla JS and then scroll till the element that you want to click, once its visible on the screen then perform a click on it.

Hope this answers your question
:)

Comment: +1 with addition: `js.executeScript` should be used ONLY to scroll the element into view, as temporary replacement of `Action.move`, preferably in it's own helper method. Eventually, they will fix Se3 and then you can revert to doing it "the right way", so best is to have the hack in fewer places. Good tip and good to know.

Comment: The problem will not be solved by this code.
Other suggestions, please.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happen to me. This happens when your browser (in this case chrome) updates the minor version. The selenium can still load the drivers and an instance of it can be instantiated, because it (probably) checks the major version.

I was using the scroll action with JS, so after the update it didn't work, but only this didn't work in running mode, scrolling using JS. Though it still worked fine in debug. Maybe it's something related to JS, in running mode that cause this problem.

Solution : update your webdriver and check the minor version to match.